# WPF Rendered Color inconsistency with Opacity on Brush and Control Elements

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, opacity, brush

Considering the following xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="PlayTabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="HintColor" A="255" R="0" G="0" B="0"></Color>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HintColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource HintColor}" Opacity="0.26"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Background="White">
        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
                    Text="Hello World, #42000000" 
                    Foreground="#42000000"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource HintColorBrush}"
                    Text="Hello World, HintColorBrush @ 0.26" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
                Text="Hello World, #68000000" 
                Foreground="#68000000"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
                    Foreground="Black"
                    Opacity="0.26"
                    Text="Hello World, Black TB@0.26" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontWeight="ExtraBlack"
                    Foreground="#FFbdbdbd"
                    Text="Hello World, #FFbdbdbd" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

The observation to take from this is that Line1 and Line2 are of different colour. Line 3 is visually correct but numerically incorrect in terms of its colour input.
Here is what is done to each line of Textblock.

1. Hard code Foreground colour of #42000000. This is approximately 26% opacity. Result: Incorrect
2. Brush resource of opacity of 0.26 with the color set to Black effectively. Result: Incorrect
3. The corrected numeric to produce the same perceived output. Which is in theory 40.6% opacity.
4. Using the Textblock's Opacity 0.26. Result: Correct
5. Hard coded colour of #FFbdbdbd, no transparency involved. Result: Correct

My question is: What/Why is wpf rendering this differently? This makes it difficult to reliably do colour styling when transparency is concern from a designer's sample/screenshot.

Note that out of curiosity, I have done this on a Windows store app as well. And the result is what I would expect, all the colours are the same except Line3 which will now be darker as it is more opaque.

Comment: You'll want to research the difference between RGBa and Opacity

Comment: @ChrisW. What's your point? If you would apply the different brushes and opacities to something else than text (e.g. the Stroke of a Line) you wouldn't notice these differences.

Comment: @Clemens yea sorry about that, obviously if there was a specific point than I'd have provided a specific answer. While although I think I have a good idea towards the culprit I'll have to swing back around when I have more free time than to just leave a vague directional response. Cheers

Comment: @ChrisW. Well, I'm curious...

Comment: @Clemens I know you are amigo, so am I :D

Comment: This [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6605534/1136211) was asked a while ago, although without a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has stumbled into this issue as well, it seems that setting [TextOptions.TextFormattingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.textoptions.textformattingmode?view=net-5.0) to [Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.textformattingmode?view=net-5.0) seems to fix the issue (you can set this at Window level so it affects all content). This does change the text rendering layout a bit though, so take that into consideration. See [this](https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/05/17/822-deciding-which-textformattingmode-to-use/) for a bit more info on what's the difference.